# Recursive SQL (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL query where the table has fields  OriginalDocket, Docket, DiversionDocket that are linked

```
Declare @DespatchFrom date = '02-01-2021' 

select OriginalDocket, Docket, DiversionDocket 
from trans 
where DespatchDateTime >= @DespatchFrom
and originaldocket <> '' 
and DiversionDocket <> ''
```

[image]

The above I want to write to show like

[image]

Code for 2nd image:

```
select t.OriginalDocket, t.Docket, t.DiversionDocket, t2.DiversionDocket as DiversionDocket2
from trans t, trans t2
where t.DespatchDateTime >= @DespatchFrom
and t.originaldocket <> '' 
and t.DiversionDocket <> '' 
and t2.OriginalDocket = t.DiversionDocket
and t2.diversiondocket <> ''
```

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: Evolve - don't use [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: What is your question?  Do you have an issue (apart from the appalling use of `,` in the `FROM` clause)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select 
    inner.OriginalDocket,
    outer.OriginalDocket, 
    inner.DiversionDocket, 
    outer.DiversionDocket as DiversionDocket2
from
    docketTable as inner
join
    docketTable as outer on inner.Docket = outer.OriginalDocket
where
    inner.DespatchDateTime >= @DespatchFrom
    and inner.originaldocket <> '' 
    and inner.DiversionDocket <> ''
```